# Registry in session implementation

Tags: session, go, registry

I'm trying to understand the session implementation from gorilla. There is a concept of `Registry` in it, registry seems to be the mapping of multiple session and a request. I'm curious, what is the use case here for registry ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A `Registry` hold one or more named sessions for the request. A request could use a mix of `CookieStore`s and or `FileSystem` stores (or others that they implement / import like a BoltDB Store), each holding one or more named sessions.